# Save response from view to a file

Tags: django

Is it possible, before the controller action returns the output from the view, to save it to file?

Comment: Yes.  Anything else you'd like to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Django view is simply a Python function that returns an HTTPResponse.  It can do anything else it likes.